# GCM ios not working if notification payload is included

Tags: php, ios, curl, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Here is the code is use to send messages to my ios application from a php script:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $devices,
    'data' => array("message"=>"hi")
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

This code is functional but I want to be able to send push notifications not just messages. However, when I include the notification payload as described in the Google cloud messaging documentation, the method application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is not called.

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $devices,
    'content_available' => true ,
    'notification' => array("title" => "title", "body"=>"body"),
    'data' => array("message"=>"hi")
);
```

I have an apns development certificate and I have registered my app for notifications in the delegate. I have also successfully obtained a device token from google. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You do know you're sending your payload to the Google API and not to Apple's?

Comment: yes we are supposed to do that gcm sends it to apple https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#http_post_request

Comment: That's the first time I've heard of that. You sure you don't want to use the official Apple API?

Comment: If I don't find a solution to my issue I think i will but gcm is more convenient for me since all the server side of my android application  has already been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing on an Apple Watch. The `title` key in `notification` is only used in a Watch according to here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref.

You should try with only a `body` key in your `notification` dictionary and then see if it works or not.